# date/time field value out of range: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT dblink_exec('dbname=sie7IAG110527A74',
' INSERT INTO public.catalogo_maestro(
      id, codigo, tipoc, nombre, tipo, ctamayor, idrubro, afectable, "timestamp", status, idctasup, naturaleza, idbitacora, tipoc2)
      VALUES (1,''_GLOBAL'',NULL,''Cuenta GLOBAL'',''CG'',0,0,0,''0000-00-00 00:00:00'',1,0,''D'',NULL,NULL);');
```

¿Saben por que me sale este error?

> date/time field value out of range: "0000-00-00 00:00:00" en postgres

Comment: No puedes ponerle 0000-00-00 a un date time, por qué no mejor lo pones NULL?

Comment: SELECT dblink_exec('dbname=sie7IAG110527A74',' INSERT INTO public.catalogo_maestro(
id, codigo, tipoc, nombre, tipo, ctamayor, idrubro, afectable, timestamp, status, idctasup, naturaleza, idbitacora, tipoc2)
VALUES (1,''_GLOBAL'',NULL,''Cuenta GLOBAL'',''CG'',0,0,0, ''NULL'',1,0,''D'',NULL,NULL);');      
HORA ME MANDA ESTE ERROR LE PUSE EL NULL PERO NO SE PUEDE ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "NULL"

Comment: sin las comillas.... No `"NULL"`, sino `NULL`.